# Principal Component Analysis output interpretation

Tags: data-mining

[image]

I am not exactly getting what that selected attributes means....I tried with iris and german dataset and got the first 2 and 10 attributes as result.....whether it gives the first attributes or anything related to rank(rank is also in decreasing order of attribute order in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCA creates new axes based on your data's variance distribution. It's like rotating x-y axes with respect to your data. New axes will be linear combinations of the old ones, e.g. $a_1=0.2\hat{x}+0.5\hat{y}$. I didn't use Weka, but it seems the four entries in the form $\sum{a_kA_k}$ represents your principal axes, in decreasing order with respect to explained variance.